# robot.mouseMove not moving to a proper location with Video Evidence

Tags: java, class, mouse, mousemove, awtrobot

This is one of the weirdest problems I have encountered in my programming. When I use the robot class to move my cursor, it wont move it to the proper location on the first try. It seems to "lock in" and get closer each to time to the specified location. I attached a link below to a youtube video I uploaded showing this. The program is listed below, and is very simple. It moves the cursor to the same location 25 times, and prints out the cursor location after each attempt using MouseInfo.getPointerLocation. When I would click the run button, it would try to move the mouse to a specified value, getting closed and closer each time, usually taking around three time. I have tried updating the version of eclipse I am using, and the java. My research has shown people having this issue and cite a bug from OpenJDK. I am not sure if this causes the problem, or if it has been fixed or how to update it. Thanks. Here is the link to the video:

https://youtu.be/VfYTPcbW6iY
Important note for the video: Because I recorded it with bandicam, it hides the mouse, so the program clicks everytime at a new position. The red circle indicates where it is clicking. The program is listed below. This bug happens every time, and ever since I updated java on my computer around a year ago I have been running into this. I show it twice in the video first with the coordinates of (1037,456), and then I change it to (500,500) for the second time.

```
import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.MouseInfo;
import java.awt.Robot; 
import java.awt.event.InputEvent;

public class tester {
    static Robot g;
    public static void main(String args[]) throws AWTException{
        g = new Robot();
        for(int i = 0; i < 25; i++) {
            g.mouseMove(500,500);
            g.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
            g.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
            System.out.println("x: " + MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().x + " y: " + MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().y);
            g.delay(500);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: wow in 1080p,good.

Comment: I think you want to read the docs on what `Robot#delay` actually does

Comment: I moved `g.delay` outside, before, the loop and with a loop of 5 iterations, didn't have any issues.  I even moved the cursor to a different screen and had no issues